# How to install sklearn2pmml correctly in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas, sklearn2pmml

I have been trying to install sklearn2pmml using pip
`pip install --upgrade sklearn2pmml==0.83.0`
`pip install --upgrade sklearn2pmml`
`pip install sklearn2pmml`
`python3 -m pip install sklearn2pmml`

I have tried all variations to pip install command. But I am still getting the same error (shown below)

```
pip install --upgrade sklearn2pmml==0.83.0
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting sklearn2pmml==0.83.0
  Using cached sklearn2pmml-0.83.0.tar.gz (6.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4rirpdmx/sklearn2pmml_8f0847b696dd4b058e058b7e1e18cdda/setup.py", line 44, in <module>
          "sklearn-pandas>=0.0.10"
        File "/home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 147, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
        File "/home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 474, in __init__
          for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
        File "/home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 999, in entry_points
          return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
        File "/home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 449, in load
          ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
        File "/home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 997, in <genexpr>
          dist.entry_points for dist in unique(distributions())
        File "/home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
          k = key(element)
        File "/home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 931, in _normalized_name
          return self._name_from_stem(stem) or super()._normalized_name
        File "/home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 600, in _normalized_name
          return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
        File "/home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 855, in normalize
          return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
        File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 192, in sub
          return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
      TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have tried installing several versions. I have tried uninstalling py4j and then running it. Installing py4j's different version and the installing it.

Not sure why I am getting this error.

Has someone faced this issue before?

I have tried installing different versions of the package. I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by updating

> /home/notebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/**init**.py

file. I replaced
`return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')`
with
`return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_') if name else ''`

I am not sure why but None was getting passed to normalize function.